# How can I realise different actions (e.g. change scenery, interact with npc, pick up items) using the input system of Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using the (new) input system of Unity and have the problem to realise an interaction with different objects. I am still quite new to Unity and hope to find some help.
I have created an event (OnInteract) that listens to whether e has been pressed.

[image]

Next I created an object with a collider into which my player can run. Whenever the player meets a certain collider, something should happen. In my case I want to change the scene. However, on my initial scene there are two doors that the player can open by pressing e. I have given both doors the same layer name because they are both exits.

Basically, it works that I can only press e when I hit this particular collider. However, I don't know how to do it instead of performing two different actions. Maybe there is a way to give the objects a script that I can trigger via the PlayerMovement script. Without taking it into the player.

this is my script that works so far:

```
    void OnInteract(InputValue value)
{
    if (myBoxCollider.IsTouchingLayers(LayerMask.GetMask("Entrance")))
    {
        Debug.Log("interact with the door");
    }
}
```

or is there perhaps a way to listen to the "tag" instead of the layer?
I have also come across interfaces, but have not really understood how these help me. Or how I have to use them here to make them work.

Answer (score 0):

In the end you're going to have to check some kind of tag, layer, or reference a component. it's just your preference. To make it a little simpler you can shoot a raycast in the direction you are looking to check for objects instead of having colliders. But in the end it's doing the same thing.

I don't really use interfaces as I'm pretty new myself but from what I can tell they are generally used for organization and global accessibility in similar objects, like doors lol.